# Straighten a spline using derivatives to determine rotation at each point

Tags: python, scipy

I'm working on straightening splines as a component of my larger project to straighten curved text.

After fitting a spline to my data points, I use scipy's `splev` to get the derivative of the spline at each point along the curve. Since the derivative gives me the slope of the tangent to the curve at a given point (unless I'm very confused), I determine the rotation needed to produce a straight line by comparing the derivative to a line with 0 slope.

Having established the rotation needed at each point to straighten my spline, I loop over each point and apply the corrective rotation to the current point and each preceding point.

The relevant code follows:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import arange
from scipy import interpolate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import random

def rotate(origin, point, angle):

    ox, oy = origin
    px, py = point

    qx = ox + math.cos(angle) * (px - ox) - math.sin(angle) * (py - oy)
    qy = oy + math.sin(angle) * (px - ox) + math.cos(angle) * (py - oy)

    return qx, qy

xxx = [0,2,4,4,2,0]
yyy = [0,2,4,6,8,10]

tckp, u = interpolate.splprep([xxx, yyy], s=3, k=2, nest=-1)

xpointsnew, ypointsnew = interpolate.splev(u, tckp)

dx, dy = interpolate.splev(u, tckp, der=1)
fullder = dy/dx

rotating_x = xxx
rotating_y = yyy
index = -1
for i in fullder:
    index += 1
    corrective_rotation = -(math.degrees(math.atan(0)-math.atan(fullder[index])))
    print(corrective_rotation)
    rotation_center = [rotating_x[index], rotating_y[index]]
    target_indices = np.arange(0,index,1)
    for i in target_indices:
        rotation_target = [rotating_x[i], rotating_y[i]]
        qx, qy = rotate(rotation_target,rotation_center,math.radians(corrective_rotation))
        rotating_x[i] = qx
        rotating_y[i] = qy

print(rotating_x)
print(rotating_y)

plt.plot(xpointsnew, ypointsnew, 'r-')
plt.plot(rotating_x, rotating_y, 'b-')
plt.show()
```

What I'm doing isn't working, but I'm not sure why. Not only is the resulting line not straight, it's also much shorter than the original curve. Is the approach outlined above fundamentally flawed in some way? Am I doing something stupid in my code? I would really appreciate a second pair of eyes.

Comment: You define rotate method and you do not use it at all.

Comment: @MishaVacic I don't? I'm pretty sure I do here:  `qx, qy = rotate(rotation_target,rotation_center,math.radians(corrective_rotation))`

Answer (score 0):

A fundamental flaw of the algorithm is that it takes slope at a point as the amount of necessary rotation of one of two segments in which that point divides the curve. As an example, consider a straight line at 60 degrees. Your algorithm  will produce rotation of 60 degrees at every knot of the line, in effect making them all 120-degree angles.

You are not rotating the entire curve, only a part of it (up to `index` in your version; after `i` in my version). The appropriate amount of rotation is how sharply the curve turns at that point, which is reflected by the change of its slope — not the slope itself.

Then there are minor details like

- incorrect order of rotation_center and rotation_target in the list of arguments;
- pointless conversion to degrees and back;
- using `atan(dy/dx)` where `atan2(dy, dx)` should be used;
- and the strange decision to rotate from the end of the curve.

Here is my version; the only changes are in the for loop.

```
for i in range(len(xxx)-1):
    corrective_rotation = -(math.atan2(dy[i+1], dx[i+1]) - math.atan2(dy[i], dx[i])) 
    print(corrective_rotation)
    rotation_center = [rotating_x[i], rotating_y[i]]
    for k in range(i+1, len(xxx)):
        rotation_target = [rotating_x[k], rotating_y[k]]
        qx, qy = rotate(rotation_center, rotation_target, corrective_rotation)   
        rotating_x[k] = qx
        rotating_y[k] = qy
```

[image: straightened]

By the way, `plt.axes().set_aspect('equal')` helps avoid the illusion that the curve changed length after rotation.

Finally, I should say that taking angles from the point values of the derivative of an interpolating spline is a very questionable decision. Finite differences at an appropriate scale are more robust.